# write/read file performance issue in C

Tags: c, performance, file-io

I have performance issues with reading and writing files in C. Here is my problem and solution, but it's slow:

I have an ASCII file and I consider every line in it a record. I have to split this file into two based on a certain number present at some position in the file.
For instance, if the number at position 10 is 0 the record goes to file1 and if it is 1 the record goes to file2.

What I have done is that I open the input file and two other file streams for output files. I read one row from input file, make a comparison and the row either goes to file1 or file2 and then the next record is read.
It is working fine, but it is very slow. Please advise a way to do this faster.

Here is how the file is being read:

```
bytes_read = readline(infile, (void*)buffer, line_size+1);
```

fwrite is used to write in files. The size of files is about 50 MB. The files are closed after reading the whole input file.

Comment: You should show us the relevant code.  There are fast and slow ways to code file I/O.  Maybe you're doing something silly.

Comment: Thanks paddy for comment. I have added more information/code in question. Please help.

Comment: Why are you seeking?  That will be costing you a lot.  If you want to discard the next 384 bytes, just do `fread` instead - by default the `stdio` file streams are buffered.  If you really want to seek, at least use `SEEK_CUR`.

Comment: Thanks Paddy, let me explore SEEK_CUR.

Comment: Give an example of your "lines"

Comment: Alberto, it simple line of any numbers

Answer (score 1):

You've pretty much got the fastest way right there!

- What type of IO have you got? Buffered/unbuffered?
- How big are the files?
- Do you open/close the output files for each line, or keep them open?
- Any seeking in the output files?
- Which part is slow, read? write? both?

IO is one of the slower parts of a program. Some code may help us spot any obvious issues.

Comment: Thanks John for reply. I have added information in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to read the file in blocks rather than a line at a time.  Block reading can be much faster than line by line reading.  If you can read the whole thing into memory, great.  If not, read a large block, process it and move on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read all files into some arrays and work on variables/arrays, not directly on IO.

Of course if this is possible (you have few files, not hundreds).

If there are hundreds or thousands of these files - then you should consider another data storage method. Databases are designed for things like this.

Another option is MySQL with CSV storage engine.

[The CSV Storage Engine at mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/csv-storage-engine.html)

but that last may force you to change files structure anyway.

Comment: Thanks dear for reply. Files are in thousands.

Comment: Then you should consider another data storage method. Databases are designed for things like this.

Comment: databases have their own limits. But I have to do in files ways :)

Comment: How big these files are? Maybe reading them into RAM at application start is not so bad idea?

Comment: Files are more than 50 MB in size and a max of 150 MB

Comment: So reading them all is bad idea. Reading whole file when you need it is bad idea too (reading 50MB text file will take about 0.5 second on 7200RPM hard disk).

Answer (score 0):

You may try to reduce number of read/write calls.

1. Try to read 2k bytes once instead of getline(). Or even read the whole file once if your file is not huge.
2. Use buffered write. And don't close file after each write. Only close file after you finish writing the whole file.

Comment: Thanks Li for you reply.If I have 50 MB to 70 MB file, is it ok to load whole file in memory?

Comment: Today computers have a lot of memory, and 'silly' web browser with few pages opened can eat 100-200MB of RAM, so why your serious and productive program can't use so much ram?

Comment: Thanks Kamil. I think its better to be loaded in memory.

Comment: Im not sure how your application works, but if you often have to access many random files - reading whole file into RAM may take more time than your old method. I mean - there is no sense to load whole file when you need one line from it, and after this you need to open another file.

Comment: I did ever work on a similar project, so I think 70M is not too big. If you load the 70M file once into memory, then parse line by line in memory, it should be significantly faster than read line by line from file.

Answer (score 0):

After discussion in comments I think there is no simple answer for your question.

Effective reading and writing on thousands of CSV files with big size is really hard.

Databases with better storage engines were invented to avoid performance problems like this.

Maybe you should take a look how CSV engine is designed in some open source database. There you should find (very complicated) answer for your question: what is the best way to handle many big csv files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading from a file, then it is preferable to use fgets. This automatically moves the file pointer for the next fgets.

fseek and ftell are slowing things down in your code.  Try this.  It should be much faster.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main()
{
    char line[132];
    int line_num = 0;
    FILE *fp_r, *fp_w1, *fp_w2, *fp_w;

    fp_r = fopen("readfile", "r");
    if (fp_r == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open testfile\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    fp_w1 = fopen("writefile1", "w");
    if (fp_w1 == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open writefile1\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    fp_w2 = fopen("writefile2", "w");
    if (fp_w1 == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open writefile2\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp_r) != NULL) {
        line_num++;

        if (*(line+9) == '0') {
            fp_w = fp_w1;
        }
        else if (*(line+9) == '1') {
            fp_w = fp_w2;
        }
        else {
            printf("Exiting - Error at line %d\n", line_num);
            exit(1);
        }

        fprintf(fp_w, line);
    }

    fclose(fp_r);
    fclose(fp_w1);
    fclose(fp_w2);

    exit(0);
}
```

The readfile I used was

```
01234567 0 This is the line with 0 at position 10
01234567 1 This is the line with 1 at position 10
```

Comment: Thank you Arun for your reply.I am using readline only. Anyway let me give try to fgets.